# What's IE8 equivalent of Chrome and Firefox/Firebug inspect element?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I'm currently having some issue for my web app in IE8 only. Does anyone know if there's an IE plugin which is similar to Chrome or Firefox/Firebug inspect element?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You use [Internet Explorer Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: +1 Internet Explorer by default has script debugging capabilities. Also you can download Visual Studio 2008, attach IE & debug scripts

Comment: Just press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the IE dev tools.

Answer (score 19):

To inspect an element open the developer tools and click the arrow icon in the tool bar (select element by click) or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. Then just click on the element you want to inspect.

Comment: unfortunately you can't click down into the contents of an iframe (as of the ie9 beta) - it'll just select the iframe element, and you have to drill down through the frame's contents yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You might also try [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite). You can use it as a bookmarklet if you want or just embed it in your page it seems.